# How to disable request caching in AFNetworking iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, caching, afnetworking

I noticed that inside my iOS app there is a file called **"cache.db"** which contains all of the **requested urls** such as "*http:/ /mywebsite.com/api/find.php?id=DEVICE_ID&secret=MY_SECRET*" .

I'm using AFNetworking for all of the http and https requests and I do believe that I did not set any caching policy for it. How do I remove or stop the app from caching the requested urls ? I do not want my users ( those who have root access to their phones/ jailbroken devices ) to see those urls.

Meanwhile, here is example of my get request

```
-(void){

    // Obtain Manager
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [self getHTTPRequestOperationManager];
    [manager GET:_path parameters:[self getRequestParams] success:[self getOperationSuccessBlock]
         failure:[self getOperationFailureBlock]];
}

- (AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)getHTTPRequestOperationManager {
    self.operationManager = [APlacesProviderRequest manager:_basePath];
    return self.operationManager;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of how you send request using AFNetworking.

Comment: @KudoCC I just edited my post

Answer (score 1):

From [AFNetworking github site](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide#nsurlsession--afurlsessionmanager):

> Unlike NSURLConnection objects, which each share application-wide
>   settings for session management, cache policies, cookie storage, and
>   URL protocols, NSURLSession objects can configure these all
>   individually. Once a session is initialized with a particular
>   configuration, it can dispatch tasks to fetch data, and upload or
>   download files.

So I guess you might experiment with that property (I haven't rooted device so I cannot check if what will work).

Anyway you can try: `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];`